# page redirection from older to new url c#

Tags: c#, .net, redirect

I have developed one existing site with new technology. But my old site was developed so far ago so it is crawled in search engine. But my question starts now. In old site, there was one page url : root/abc?type=xyz, and now in development url is like : root/mnp/xyz.

Now What I have to do to redirect from old url to new url? I don't want to rewrite url, only redirection should be done. Guide me for it.

Thanks,

Dipa

Comment: *"I don't want to rewrite url only redirection should be done"* - add code to redirect to new page, in old page?

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: My new site is in umbraco

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be making a javascript function that runs when the window loads, and all it does it redirection to the new website. 
Put that script in the old website, and then if anyone tries to get to your old website it would just redirect him to the new one.

Comment: My old site is deleted. not able to access it. I have access in only new developed site.

Comment: @Dipa if you don't have access to the old url than you can't prevent from people to go there, even if there is no server at that end. However, if it's on the same domain, you can just make a new page in the old site location with the redirection.

Comment: yes I will publish that new site in same url. My old site was on www.site.com and going to use same for new site.

Now can you guide me how to add new page in server as you told. I don't know how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: @Dipa Unfortunately I have no experience with Umbraco, so I can't really tell how you make pages in it... I kinda assumed you know how since you made a whole website with it.  However, in every web page adding a javascript code should be pretty easy. Just adding a script with window.location="newURL" should do the work

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a content page in Umbraco with URL "root/abc" and add redirection code in the first few lines of the corresponding template (razor view) for the page.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

You need to tell *Search Engine* that your old URL no more exists and it has been replaced with a new one. Asp.net provides a very simple way to perform this job.

You just have to call [`Response.RedirectPermanent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.redirectpermanent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). It sends the response **301** to *Search Engine* that this URL has been replaced with the new one.

**For Example:**

```
Response.RedirectPermanent("root/mnp/xyz");
```

You can read a bit more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537955/response-redirect-vs-response-redirectpermanent).

**Your approach should be:**

But in your case the problem is your old site doesn't exist anymore. So you will have to do some extra work here:

1. Create a site based on web-forms and add all the pages on which you want to perform redirection
2. On page load event of every form do `RedirectPermanent` to new URL
3. Host the site on same domain

**Sample:**

I am providing here a sample for the example you have in the question:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string type = Request.QueryString["type"];
    if (type != null)
    {
        Response.RedirectPermanent("root/mnp/" + type);
    }   
}
```

[A comprehensive tutorial about the topic](http://www.dotnettutorials.com/tutorials/advanced/aspnet-permanent-redirect/).