# Reuse old aspx routes in Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side

We are writing a new version of an old page that other pages are dependent on. As such it's important to keep old routing.

One of the routes is as follows:

```
https://example.com/area/page.aspx?id=123
```

I would like for this to work, but point to a blazor component.
I have tried adding it as a @page supplement to the ones I already have, but the application wont run with it.

```
@page "/page/{id}/{property:int?}"
@page "/page/{id}"
@page "/area/page.aspx?id={id}"
```

I have also tried just

```
@page "/area/page.aspx
```

but this seems not to work either. Blazor isn't even starting when I do this. I also tested

```
@page "/area/page.tst
```

to no avail. I believe that it's the `.` and `?` that is the culprits.

A solution might be to redirect from the old URL to the component, with something that the @page directive can handle, but I can't figure out where in the middleware this would be done.

Question is basically: Which ways one can reuse old URL's with Blazor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that in `Startup.cs` there's a method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
```

That has this in it:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

Here I could just add the following line:

```
endpoints.MapGet("/area/page.aspx", async x => { x.Response.Redirect("~/page/"); });
```

And it would redirect. Nifty :)

Resulting code would then be:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapGet("/area/page.aspx", async x => { x.Response.Redirect("~/page/"); });
});
```

Comment: You may also want to add another parameter `true` to `x.Response.Redirect("~/page/", true)` to do a permanent redirect.

Comment: I found this one as an explanation to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537955/response-redirect-vs-response-redirectpermanent#:~:text=to%20Gunnar%20Peipman%2C-,Response.,URL%20given%20by%20Location%20header.

Comment: Yes thats correct. The permanent redirect is just to tell browsers/search engines that URL has been changed permanently by returning a HTTP 301 code. I can't say for sure, if it works or not with query strings, but have a look at URL rewrite rules in web.config aswell

Comment: Nice thanks!
I'm also adding x.Request.QueryString to get parameters as well, ex:
endpoints.MapGet("/AspPage.aspx", async x => { x.Response.Redirect("BlazorPage" + x.Request.QueryString, true); });